# Adding ObjectID manually in MongoDB (Rails/Mong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm working with Rails 4.0 and MongoDB (Mongoid) and I have the following Code to create Documents:

```
    lines.each do |l|
    Insert.create(:position => 0, :content => l, :schema_id => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string("52419d2f80a9b88bb9000002"))
    end
```

This works fine and I get the following output in my Mongo-Database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5241ff1280a9b8f16e000057"
},
"position": "0",
"content": "blabla",
"schema_id": "52419d2f80a9b88bb9000002"
```

}

The only Problem is, that I want to have a "$oid": before the actual schema_id like this:

```
...
    "schema_id": {
    "$oid": "52419d2f80a9b88bb9000002"
}
```

and I really got confuse of how I can insert that "$oid" followed by a colon manually....

Would be great if you could help me...

Thx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have `$oid` at all, neither in your schema_id or in _id , that would make indexing operations hard, or not possible into Mongodb. You probably have $oid because you could be parsing the document to a json in inserting in the DB somehow, anyways, If I were you, I would write a migration to fix this in the db layer, and fix the code to not use the JSON version before persisting.

Comment: Well, the $oid in _id seems to be generated automatically? How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is like Arthur's, and I'll try to clarify.  You should re-examine your Ruby code and make sure that you are not somehow implicitly stringifying your object ids in some Ruby code that you did not put in your question.

Your question is confusing to me as I try to decipher it, and probably confusing to you as you try to debug.  This is because you are working in Ruby and yet give us the documents in JSON that are not from Ruby nor from the mongo shell, suggesting that you are trying to debug from a context separate from the code in question.

I gently suggest that you follow the standard Rails practice of writing tests.  Please write a test that recreates your problem by inserting documents and dumps the document in question using Ruby.